# Which button toggle bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap modal form, and several buttons, calling this form, like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#specialoffer">
    <button class="green full" id="button1">Ask Question</button>
</a>
```

Can I send information, which button toggle modal form to modal form? I want to have something like this, in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="caller" value="button1">
```

where "button1" is an id of the button, user pressed to activate the modal.

Comment: short answer is: yes

Comment: I need some details about that :)

Comment: for example you can have a form that wraps both the link+hidden input  and the body of the modal

Comment: @СергейСоколов, what about my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[type="button"]').click(function(e){
    var val = $(e.target).closest('button').attr('data-value');

  $('#myModal').find('input').val(val);
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Try this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iboylmz/mhhksL2r/1/). This is what you need.

Comment: Looks like your fiddle link is broke

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need!

Comment: You can use bootbox.js (http://bootboxjs.com/). It helps creating modal with dynamic content and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the modal window, you need to use a button or a link.

You can listen the `show.bs.modal` event, when you try to open a modal by click a button.

Please try this:

```js
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var trigger = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $('.modal').find('.modal-body').empty().append('<input type="text" value="'+trigger.attr('id')+'"/>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" id="button1" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Show Modal</button>

<button type="button" id="button2" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Show Modal2</button>

<button type="button" id="button3" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Show Modal3</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have several buttons. And one modal. I have a form in this modal. And I need to know, WHICH button pressed, to send this information by my form. It should looks smth. like this:  <input type="hidden" name="caller" value="button1">
where "button1" is an id of the button, user pressed to activate the modal.

Comment: @СергейСоколов , I updated my answer. Now must be work.

Comment: @СергейСоколов, I updated with another method. Please see now.